# Saving MATLAB structures to be read in C++ using HDF5

Tags: c++, matlab, hdf5

I am attempting to write an HDF5 file that will save a bunch of structures created in MATLAB, that will then be read in C++. These structures contain data that is not necessarily numeric such as strings, cell arrays, and sub-structures, so using `hdf5write` is out.

However, calling `save` with the argument `'-v7.3'` saves to HDF5, so is it possible to read these files in C++/C and extract the data? Is it even a good idea?

Is it a better idea to create a custom datatype for each structure and write a custom HDF5 writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're goal is to share a common file format between C/C++ and MATLAB you can use the [matio library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matio) which can read/write the same .mat format that you read/write directly from MATLAB, including cells, structures, etc.